# Github not picking up changes after removing .git folder from sub directory

Tags: git, github

I have a project which has two directories frontend and backend.

Inside `project` I had a `.git` Initialized, however, I noticed that inside the frontend directory there was a `.git` file causing the white arrow to appear on the folder. I removed that `.git` folder. However, right now GitHub is not picking up any changes on the frontend directory. I was wondering how I can set it to pick up those changes?

my structure is:

```
project
--.git
--backend
--frontend
-----project_frontned_src
--.gitignore
```

When I go to `project/frontend` and run `git add .`

I get an error:

```
fatal: in unpopulated submodule 'frontend/project_frontned_src'
```

Comment: @matt yes I did run `git add frontend` .And no the `.gitignore` Is not there to ignore the frontend

Answer (score 1):

The nested git repository was probably configured as a submodule. Try navigating to project/, then running `git submodule deinit frontend/project_frontend_src` ([documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-deinit-f--force--all--ltpathgt82308203)).

Answer (score -1):

It appears you've removed the `.git` file from a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), breaking that submodule. You should restore the submodule via `git submodule update frontend`, and avoid removing the `.git` file.